# Put even characters in uppercase, but skipping spaces

Tags: java, arrays, string, character

I'm trying to convert some text so that every even character becomes uppercase. This works, but if there's a space between words, the code takes the space as a character too. So for example, if the input text is "this is a test", the output is "tHiS Is a tEsT". I want it to ignore the spaces and give "tHiS iS a TeSt" as output.

I now have the following code:

```
private String result;
private String letter;

private void generateText() {

    result = "";

    String input = editTextInput.getText().toString();
    String lowerCase = input.toLowerCase();
    char[] charArray = lowerCase.toCharArray();

    for(int i=0;i<charArray.length;i++){
        if(String.valueOf(charArray[i]).equals(" ")){
            //I don't know what to put here
            letter = String.valueOf(charArray[i]);
        }else{
            if(i%2 == 0){
                letter = String.valueOf(charArray[i]);
            }else if(i%2 == 1){
                letter = String.valueOf(charArray[i]).toUpperCase();
            }
        }


        result += letter ;
    }

    Log.d("result", result);
}
```

What do I have to do to skip the spaces?
If it's possible, I would like to skip punctuation marks too, or in general, every character which is not a letter.

Thanks in advance!

(For those who are wondering, I'm making a Spongebob meme text generator app)

Comment: How would you do it, without any code, in your head?

Comment: *FYI:* `String.valueOf(charArray[i]).equals(" ")` is better written as `charArray[i] == ' '`

Comment: For `"this is a test"`, shouldn't the output be `"tHiS iS a TeSt"`? `"tHiS"` ends with an upper case letter, therefore, `"iS"` should start with a lower case letter?

Comment: @beatngu13 That is what question says is the desired result. Read it again.

Comment: @Andreas you're right, my bad.

Comment: @Andreas I did that first but Android Studio told me that strings should better be compared with the equals method ;)

Comment: @ThomasDevriese no, that's not possible, because charArray[i] and `' '` are not Strings. They're a char. A char is a primitive type.

Comment: @JBNizet String.valueOf returns a String right? But I get what you're saying, it's easier to just lose the string.valueOf and do it your way. Thanks

Comment: @ThomasDevriese You seem to miss the point where `charArray[i] == ' '` is comparing `char` values, not `String` values.

Comment: @Andreas I get it now, I'm not that familiar with chars yet. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do alternate logic in a loop, you could normally use `i % 2 == 0`, or `(i & 1) == 1`, but since the alternation is conditional, you need a variable to store the "state". With simple alternation, a `boolean` variable is the obvious choice.

Also, continuously converting each `char` to a `String` is bad for performance. Just update the `char[]`.

```
private static String upperEven(String input) {
    char[] buf = input.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    boolean upper = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(buf[i])) {
            if (upper)
                buf[i] = Character.toUpperCase(buf[i]);
            upper = ! upper;
        }
    }
    return new String(buf);
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(upperEven("this IS a TEST"));
```

*Output*

```
tHiS iS a TeSt
```

---

Code can be compressed/obscured to this: ;-)

```
private static String upperEven(String s) {
    char[] c = s.toCharArray();
    boolean t = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
        if (Character.isLetter(c[i]))
            c[i] = ((t = ! t) ? Character.toLowerCase(c[i]) : Character.toUpperCase(c[i]));
    return new String(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This is my solution.

private static void generateText() {
        String result = "";
        String input = "i am a engineer and student of nit.";
        String lowerCase = input.toLowerCase();
        Boolean isLower = false;
        char[] charArray = lowerCase.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < lowerCase.length(); i++) {
            String letter = String.valueOf(charArray[i]);
            if (!Character.isLetter(charArray[i])) {
                result += letter;
            } else {
                if(isLower)
                    letter = letter.toUpperCase();
                result += letter;
                isLower = !isLower;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Comment: That works, but here's some criticism for improvement: 1) `isLower` should be `boolean`, not `Boolean`. --- 2) To build up a string one character at a time, use a `StringBuilder`. `String += String` is bad for performance. --- 3) Variable `letter` can obviously store a non-letter, so it's badly named. --- 4) There is actually no need to convert `charArray[i]` to `String`. `String += char` works too.

Comment: @andreas Thnak you for valueable comments :)